# How can I make Flask-Assets regenerate SCSS every request when debug mode is enabled?

Tags: python, flask, flask-assets

Here is how I set up `flask-assets` for scss:

```
def configure_extensions(app):
  # Web Assets
  from app.extensions import assets
  scss = Bundle(
    'scss/all.scss',
    filters='scss',
    output='scss_all.css'
  )
  assets.register('scss_all', scss)
  assets.init_app(app)
```

In my config, I set `ASSETS_DEBUG = True`

This works, and generates the file `app/static/scss_all.scss` and the folder `app/static/.webassets.cache`. The styles appear on the site as intended.

The problem, though, is if I want to regenerate the scss style sheet, I must delete the files mentioned above. This is tedious when playing around with scss.

Is there a way to regenerate these files automatically with the reloader when `app.debug` is set to `True`?

---

(aside: I'm using the dev version of flask)

Comment: webassets should only generate a new version of `scss_all.css` if you make changes to `scss/all.scss` first.

Comment: what if I change a file indirectly? For example, `all.scss` has `@import "footer"`, then I go into `footer.scss` and change a css rule. That would not trigger a reload, if I am not mistaken. I want to trigger a reload every single time the flask reloader reloads

Comment: I have the same issue, did you find a solution? I'm using the libsass filter...

Answer (score 6):

This should ideally work. But incase you are using @imports to import other scss files within the main file then you need to add the depends option. Something like;

```
mycss = Bundle(
    'app.scss',
    filters='pyscss,cssprefixer', depends=('/path/to/scss/files/**/*.scss'), output='generated/css/app.css')
assets.register('mycss)
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer by Joe should be accepted. I also implemented it in a similar way:

```
scss = Bundle('css/main.scss',
             filters='libsass',
             depends='css/*',
             output='gen/home%(version)s.css')

app = Flask(__name__)
assets = Environment(app)
assets.register('scss_all', scss)
```

all scss files are in the css directory. The main.scss imports the others. Now any change to any file in that directory will force a refresh.